# Short press on Super key opens shortcuts window [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

When I press the the `Super` key for a long time, the shortcut window opens (as it should do).

Strangely, the same happens often when I press `Super` for a short time.
Also the Icons on the Dock at the left side have numbers on them even if the shortcut window is closed and pressing a key that has a combination with Super (like `Super` + `T` for Trash) will execute the combination even if it is pressed alone (without pressing super).

It seems like Ubuntu thinks the button would be pressed permanently after pressing it once..

My Keyboard is a GXT 280 by Trust (USB and without any drivers) and works fine under windows.